# How to use CoInitializeEx with ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I am using the WinAPI function `ShellExecuteEx()` to open a folder in Windows Explorer.

According to MSDN I should always call `CoInitializeEx()` prior to using `ShellExecuteEx()` but what flags should I use for the 2nd parameter of `CoInitializeEx()`?

> There are certainly instances where ShellExecute does not use one of
>   these types of Shell extension and those instances would not require
>   COM to be initialized at all. Nonetheless, it is good practice to
>   always initalize COM before using this function.

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, What params should I use?); //COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)

ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("explore");
ShExecInfo.lpFile = pszParseName;
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: Um, try reading the line *immediately* before the text you cited. @WhozCraig UI threads should use STA, not MTA.

Comment: @RaymondChen Of course you're correct (I'd expect nothing otherwise, being a reader of your blog). I utterly lost the context form which he was invoking this. The MTA/RPC-managed-STA comment is a generality, but you're absolutely correct in pointing out what should have been obvious to me. I'll drop the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoInitializeEx()` initializes the COM-SCM for your application. You should at least call it with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`, although you are not using any COM-objects from your code so far. This means, that the calling thread will be put into its own apartment and calls to the COM-objects need to be marshalled.
There is also the option to call `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` if you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Preferably you should use this option, as it might speed up performance.
COM is quite a complicated topic, especially about apartments.